# size of screw, wall plug and drill bit for shelf upright with 7mm hole

Tags: walls, screws, drill, shelving

I have a shelf upright that has 7mm sunken holes, like this one here: https://www.twinslotshelving.co.uk/shelving-uprights/1m-white-upright

I'm just unsure about the size of the things I need for fixings.

What size drill bit should I use for the wall hole? and then what size wall plug and screw do I need?

Comment: With shelving supports like these, you'll want to be sure to use the correct sized screws (should be listed in the instructions) and drive them into the studs not just into the wallboard.

Comment: I would go out on a limb and say that you need the #10 x 2 1/2" screws listed in the "people also bought" section of the web page you linked. But, since this is a year old, it would be nice of you to come back and tell us what you did (or accept the current answer).

Answer (score 1):

I'd try my best to screw those into studs with the largest screw that will sit flush in the countersink.

If you can't line it up with studs, get the largest anchor that will fit the countersink.

Something like: https://www.renodepot.com/en/hollow-wall-anchors-0484236 and **NOT the plastic ones**. This anchor will bend out in 4 directions behind the wall board and will distribute the weight on a larger surface area.

Of course, the one I linked does not have a countersunk screw so you'll want to pick some up as well unless you don't mind the head sticking out a little.

Again, the best would be to screw these directly to a stud.